# How Can I add a header in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, header

I want the content of my gridview seperated with headers!
We can easily accomplish this in listview!
How to do this part in a gridview?

[image: This is how it has done in listview]

I want the same , as the headers has to be same and the cntent of each header must be a gridview of items! Please dont see and compare the content in the image below. its just a downloaded one!
Any help?

Comment: Post more information or post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GridView does not have columns. It is meant to arrange a flat (without columns) array of items two-dimensionally across the screen. You should use a TableLayout, which is intented to lay out columned rows.

When you use a TableLayout, you can add a header row as your first row and then add your data rows after that. There isn't a distinction between the two.

Comment: Need some help on this! any tutorial will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Hari you can add table row at dynamically after your image's row and no need to use gridview, you can only add 3 images in one table row after that you can add header row.